# Wrong black color on YouTube videos

Tags: dell, amd-graphics, colors, color-management

I have some troubles with black color on YouTube videos. See the screenshots below:

- on left - screenshot from my android phone, and there are true black color
- on right - screenshot from my ubuntu laptop and there are dark green instead black color

[image: screenshots 2-in-1]

My laptop: **DELL Inspiron 5567**, Ubuntu 16.04, with build-in Intel HD Graphics (I don't know version/model), and discrete AMD Radeon R7 M445.

I don't have installed drivers for AMD video, cause I haven't find theirs. There are no drivers for ubuntu on dell and AMD support pages for my laptop or video card. `amdgpu-pro` crashes my system, and I can't login until I remove `amdgpu-pro` in terminal mode.

I was trying to use `xgamma` and `xcalib` but didn't get good result - I can make all picture darker or make wrong green color better visible, but I can't make it black

Can somebody help me? May be anyone knows how to fix it?

P.S. Open same video in ubuntu default video player - no problem with black color.
[image: compare YouTube and default Ubuntu video player]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to fix this trouble about two weeks, and didn't get result. And I find answer immediately after create this question.

I just to disable hardware acceleration in google chrome and colors are go to be normal.

It's not good decision and I still need help with AMD drivers. But it's another question.

This question is complete. If you have some problems with colors on google chrome just try to disable hardware acceleration.